# Fs file handler for api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, fs

So I want to make a routes folder that has subfolders that contain routes but I don't know how to use fs with it...

I only know how to get files in the routes folder and not in subfolders

here is my file handler code

```
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');


module.exports = function(app){
    readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(file) {
        if (file == "index.js") return;
        var name = file.substr(0, file.indexOf('.'));
        const route = require('./' + name)
                app.get(`/${route.name}`, async (req, res) => {
                route.run(req, res)                    
                })
    });
}
```

it gets the files from the routes folder

```
-routes
  |__index.js
  |__route.js
  |__route.js
```

I want to make it so it gets routes from subfolders

```
-routes
  |__index.js
  |
  |__image routes
     |__route1.js
```

I can't find any help online...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind using external libraries i recommend using `glob`

What you want to do can be achieved with one function call:

```
const glob = require("glob");

glob("**/*.js", {cwd: __dirname}, (error, matches) => {
    if (error) return;
    console.log(matches);
})
```

This uses glob patterns to much files in a given directory, returning the whole paths like: `image-routes/route1.js` or `index.js` etc.

Comment: ok so now I have a smol problem, this works perfectly but I want to sperate the subfolders and files inside them so that I can make my routes like ```foldername/filename``` how would I be able to do such thing? *I am not asking for code just how to do it*

Comment: You can try calling a split function on the strings `matches[index].split("/")`